# Oracle USING clause out of a JOIN scope

Tags: sql, oracle

I thought that in Oracle, the `USING` clause was [only](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.10.1.2/ref/rrefsqljusing.html) used instead of `ON` to specify which columns to test for equality in the case that the two tables have a common column-name. But then I saw this:

```
create table example (

    col1           number not null,
    col2           clob not null
);

alter table example add constraint ex_pk primary key ( col1 ) using index enable;
```

what `using index enable` is doing here?

what is a list of most common uses of the `using` clause?

Comment: The `USING` keyword in the syntax for `ALTER TABLE` has nothing to do with `USING` in a `FROM` clause.

Comment: There is no "`USING` clause". There are many such clauses - one for each context in which the keyword `USING` is used. As you noted already, there is a `USING` clause in joins. There is an unrelated `USING` clause when defining a primary or unique key. There is also an unrelated `USING` clause in the `MERGE` statement. Why do you need a list of **all** possible uses of this keyword?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought that in Oracle, the USING clause was only used instead of ON
>   
> ..........
>   what is a list of most common uses of the using clause?

`USING` is just a keyword - a reserved word.
It is used in many SQL and PL/SQL commands in Oracle, some of them are:

- SELECT .... JOIN .... **USING** ....
- MERGE ..... **USING** ...
- TRANSLATE ( x **USING** y )
- CREATE JAVA .... **USING** ...
- ASSOCIATE STATISTICS .... **USING** ....
- CREATE|ALTER INDEXTYPE ..... **USING** ...
- CREATE DATABASE LINK ..... **USING** ....
- CREATE TABLE .... **USING** INDEX .....
- CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW ..... **USING** INDEX .....  **USING** ROLLBACK SEGMENT
- EXECUTE IMMEDIATE .... **USING** ....
- OPEN .... FOR .... **USING** ......

All of them you can find in the reference, search for "Oracle SQL reference" and "Oracle PL/SQL reference" using your favorite search engine, you will find these links:

- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/toc.htm
- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/toc.htm

---

From the above list I use mostly only 4: SELECT ... USING, MERGE ... USING, EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ... USING and OPEN FOR ... USING

Answer (score 1):

Quoting Tom Kyte [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f%3Fp%3D100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:32603462618660)

> It lets you specify the storage options, name, and other attributes of
>   the index that is needed for that constraint.
>
> alter table t add constraint t_pk primary key(x);
>
> will create a unique index, in your default tablespace, using whatever
>   storage parameters are the default for that tablespace.
>
> You alter table will create the index in that specified tablespace,
>   with your storage options.

such as:

```
alter table example add constraint ex_pk primary key ( col1 )
USING INDEX 
PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 
STORAGE (INITIAL 512K NEXT 512K MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 505 
PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 6 FREELIST GROUPS 2 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT) 
TABLESPACE "MY_TABLESPACE" 
ENABLE 
/
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/ADMIN/managing-indexes.htm#GUID-F6B75A7D-EF2F-4D31-BD70-C5C5D54A71DB) about the `USING`:

> You can specify details about the indexes associated with constraints.
>
> If you require more explicit control over the indexes associated with
>   UNIQUE and PRIMARY KEY constraints, the database lets you:
>
> - Specify an existing index that the database is to use to enforce the
>     constraint
> - Specify a CREATE INDEX statement that the database is to use to create
>     the index and enforce the constraint

The `ENABLE` is not related to the index but to the constraint itself.